# $f$ differentiable in $a$, $f(a)=0$, $g$ continuous $\implies fg$ differentiable in $a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

**PROBLEM:**

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ be an accumulation point in $V$. Let $f,g: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions with the following properties:

1. $f$ is differentiable in $a$ and $f(a)=0$
2. $g$ is continuous in $a$

Prove that the function $fg: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $a$ and that $(fg)'(a)=f'(a)g(a)$.

**SOURCE:**

Real analysis coursebook from Otto Forster, chapter about differentiation

**So far I have:**

I am working on the first part (showing that $fg$ is differentiable in the point $a$.
We have that

$$\exists \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\iff\exists \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a} \tag{1}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)=g(a) \tag{2}$$

And we want to show that $$\exists \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x-a}\tag{*}$$ I am stuck here. $(1)$ and $(*)$ seem to be very close, but I am not sure what arguments and theorems to use to move forward.

Comment: Multiply (1) by (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean that $fg$ is differentiable?

Well, this means the following limit must exist:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(a)}{x - a}
\end{align*}

Based on the given assumptions, we arrive at the relation:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{[f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(x) + f(a)g(x) - f(a)g(a)]}{x - a} & =
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{[f(x) - f(a)]g(x) + f(a)[g(x) - g(a)]}{x - a}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to a}\left[\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}\right]g(x)
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ is continuous at $a$, the proposed limit exists and equals $f'(a)g(a)$.

And we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be: If we knew that $c$ is differentiable then we knew from the product rule that $(fg)'(a) = f'(a)g(a) + f(a)g'(a) = f'(a)g(a)$ by $f(a)=0$. Since this does not depend on $g'$ anymore we might assume that this is in fact the derivative to $fg$ if g is only continuous.

As you’ve already seen $f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a) = f(x)g(x)$ which is the same as $(f(x)-f(a))g(x)$. Thus $(f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a))/(x-a) = (f(x)-f(a))/(x-a) \cdot g(x)$. But as $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)$ limits to $f'(a)$ this limits to $f'(a)g(a)$.